# How to change radio button color in ant design?

Tags: checkbox, radio-button, antd, ant-design-pro

I'm using antd radios and checkboxes. I want to give custom colors to them. I found answer about checkbox but found no way to change radio button color.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 19):

You can achive it by overriding following css classes:

```
.ant-radio-checked .ant-radio-inner{
  border-color: red !important ;
}

.ant-radio-checked .ant-radio-inner:after{
  background-color: red;
}

.ant-radio:hover .ant-radio-inner {
  border-color: red ;
}
```

First block is responsible for coloring the circle around the dot in radio. You can ignore !important rule but then you have to override :focus selector like:

```
.ant-radio-checked .ant-radio-inner:focus{
  border-color: red;
}
```

Second block color the dot in the middle of selected radio. The last one color circle on hover. I am not completely sure why ant-radio-inner should be inside radio:hover, but it works for me.

Comment: Do we need to reference the class in our code or it will be picked up on its own. See my post please and see if you can help there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63799078/ant-design-button-color-update

Comment: @Pabblo13 How about changing the color of the text of the radio item?

Comment: what about the ring thats around the inner dot but inside the outer perimeter?