# Ant design button color update

Tags: css, reactjs, antd, scss-mixins, ant-design-pro

I'm trying to update `Radio` `Button` colors of an [ant design](https://ant.design/components/radio/#components-radio-demo-radiobutton-solid) radio mentioned in this link in my `REACT` App.

I tried using the suggestion in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62609951/how-to-change-radio-button-color-in-ant-design) to update the colors.

But my colors are not updating. I am not sure what I'm doing incorrectly here.

Also,  Its a `REACT` project and my `package.json` has a dependency for `"antd": "^4.5.0"`
and the import for `antd.css` exists in `app.tsx` like this

```
// Global styles
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
```

This is a code I have in one of the component files of the project.

File name: `MyRadio.tsx`

```
import { Radio } from "antd";
import styles from "./mystyles.module.scss";



  return (
        <Radio.Group
          className={styles.toggle}
        >
          <Radio id="RDC" value="C">
            C
          </Radio>
          <Radio id="RDI" value="I">
            I
          </Radio>
        </Radio.Group>
      );
```

Here is how `mystyles.module.scss` looks like:

```
.toggle {
  width: 244px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
 
}
/*  Followed suggestion from other post but didnt see colors updating, when I un-comment the following code
.ant-radio-checked .ant-radio-inner {
  border-color: red !important ;
}

.ant-radio-checked .ant-radio-inner:after {
  background-color: red;
}

.ant-radio:hover .ant-radio-inner {
  border-color: red;
}
*/
```

**Update 1**

[image]

Comment: Please update your code here and send me the fork: https://codesandbox.io/s/w941j

Comment: Thanks m4n0, doing that now..

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-yonath-4kq7p

Comment: I just see an error, not your output: https://nimb.ws/PqQ4SB

Comment: Sorry m4n0, dont know why it wasnt saved. Can you please try now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the below classes. It should work. Use !important only if your css is overridden by the existing classes.
You need to import "antd/dist/antd.css"; to get these in the console and then override the css

https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-dream-4ojr4

```
.ant-radio-inner:after {
  background: red !important;
}

.ant-radio-checked .ant-radio-inner,
.ant-radio:hover .ant-radio-inner,
.ant-radio-wrapper:hover,
.ant-radio-input:focus .ant-radio-inner {
  border-color: red !important;
}
```

Edit - Included the codesandbox link and the hover css

Comment: Check this out! https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-dream-4ojr4

Comment: Thanks @anand, I see you are bringing import "antd/dist/antd.css"; Do I need to bring that in my file too if I am overriding the existing classes? Because I am not currently.

Comment: ok I see that sandbox code is updating, however I need help with my code. As you can see my radio group is using a toggle class from mystyles.module.scss, if I add your code to the .scss, I am still not seeing the colors updated.

Comment: Please check this.. https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-wildflower-je63u?file=/index.js  I am updating my post with how its looking also.

Comment: Using import "antd/dist/antd.css"; in your code lets you override the CSS. Without this, the CSS is not showing up in the console even to override.

Comment: Thanks @anand, so the project has import as a global in _app.tsx and if I add it again to my component file, I get an error Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>. Please move all global CSS imports to pages\_app.tsx. So I cant import antd css to my components files and all this code is in the component files.

Comment: I do see the antd css in the browser in dev tools and if I update it there, it works... but if I update it in my code in the project in my modules for the component, its totally ignores your code.

Comment: I updated my post with a brief structure of the project too if that helps. Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: Not sure if I can help here about the global css error @Sarah.

Answer (score 0):

I can not write comment (too low reputation), so i will write an "answer". You can try to change theme of ant-design https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme (This default blue color is primary one). However it requires some changes and new color will be applied globally, so its not too good for existing big projects.